# "It seems to me somebody will be coming after you"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you help me understand the following dialog? (The maid and the attendant is talking about a crazy patient who eats flies)

**Maid**: (Ironically) Wouldn't hurt a fly, would he?
**Attendant**: Hurt a fly? Oh, no, not him. He only *eats* 'em. Why, he'd rather eat a few blue-bottles than a pound of the best steak, and what he does to spiders is a crime.
**Maid**. It seems to me somebody will be coming after *you* in a minute, you and your spiders.
**Attendant**: I say, miss. This is a queer neighborhood.
*Dracula* dramatised by Hamilton Dean and John L. Balderston

I am not sure what the maid means by "it seems to me somebody will be coming after you." Is she trying to frighten the attendant (jokingly)? Does "somebody" mean some monster or something? I appreciate your help very much. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

They are discussing a patient in a mental hospital. The maid is jokingly suggesting that the attendant's talk of spiders suggests that he, too, may have mental health issues, and that the people who take mentally ill people to be hospitalised may be coming for him soon. In my country people often say, if they are joking about having a mental breakdown for some reason, 'The men in white coats will be coming for me soon', or 'They're coming to take me away'.

Comment: [In America as well.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnPG1v61AEk)

Comment: @JeffreyCarney - variations include 'a plain white van is coming to pick me up/take me away', or 'They're coming to measure me for a jacket that does up at the back'. The men in white coats may be further described as strong, or, gentle, or quietly spoken, or all three.